# How can i get the value of "ExternalMessageType" from the xml using xslt?

Tags: xml, xslt, xsd

I've the below xml format i need to fetch the value of "ExternalMessage"

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<entity>
   <name>Message</name>
   <type>MESSAGE</type>
   <attributes>
      <attributes_element>
         <name>ExternalMessageType</name>
         <value>Acknowledgement</value>
      </attributes_element>
```

Answer (score 0):

you can use the `value-of` element of XSLT. See description and example: 
https://www.w3schools.com/xml/xsl_value_of.asp

the XPath could be something like following:

```
<xsl:value-of select="/entity/attributes/attributes_element[name='ExternalMessageType']/value"/>
```

Comment: Thanks You very much Loic!! It worked i was struggling for a long time....

Comment: Hi mzjn, should i upvote  the answer so that it is accepted.

Comment: You should just **accept** the answer. Click the check mark. See also https://stackoverflow.com/help/accepted-answer